# Listbox turns blank when clicking on it

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I created a listbox and connected it to a table. I wrote the following code to go to record I choose from the listbox. My problem is that when I click on the listbox and code gets to "Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark" command (at a break point), the list becomes blank. This is very clear (and ugly) when there is a message to display after this line of code. Any suggestions please?

```
Private Sub lstFullName_Click()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

    rst.FindFirst "sdtID = " & Me.lstFullName.Column(1)

    If Not rst.NoMatch Then
        Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    End If

Set rst = Nothing

CheckRecordStatus ' Checks for empty fields and gives warnings.
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably should use the _AfterUpdate_ event of the listbox.

Comment: Am afraid this isn't working too.

Comment: Is listbox UNBOUND?

Comment: Yes it is unbound

Comment: Column index begins with 0. If sdtID is first column its index is 0. Usually, ID is in hidden first column. What is CheckRecordStatus? You have line for error handler but there is no ErrorHandler line to go to. Remove or comment that line.

Comment: CheckRecordStatus  is where the code that checks for empty fields and gives warning messages. The listbox turns blank whenever there is any message after this line of code:

Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark


sdtID is the second column in the query from which the listbox is getting data.

Thank you